# How can we override the global validation pipe in NestJs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I have a code in which i have applied a global validation pipe in `main.ts` file like so:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  // Enable global validation pipe
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    whitelist: true
  }));
}
```

Now in one of my controller i wanted to skip some properties of a DTO in a patch request like so

```js
    @Patch(':id')
    // Override the pipes
    @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({
        skipMissingProperties: true,
    }))
    updateProject(@Param('id') accountId: string, @Body() dataToUpdate: UpdateProjectDTO) {
        return dataToUpdate;
    }
```

This is my DTO:

```js
export class UpdateProjectDTO {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    projectType: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    projectDescription: string;
}
```

I wanted to ignore `projectDescription` if its not submitted as part of the request. But in this case my global pipe is taking precedence which doesn't have `skipMissingProperties` defined as part of its property. Is there a solution to override the global pipe?

Answer (score 2):

Overriding the global validation pipe is tricky. The solution that worked for me was to override it for a specific param decorator. The example below is for the body but the principle could be applied to other decorators as well.

First, create a raw body custom decorator:

```
export const RawBody = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext): any => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.body;
  }
);
```

Second, write another custom decorator that composes that with a new validation pipe:

```
export const AnyValidBody = () =>
  RawBody(
    new ValidationPipe({
      validateCustomDecorators: true,
      whitelist: true,
      skipMissingProperties: true
    })
  );
```

Now, in your controller use `@AnyValidBody` instead of `@Body` like so:

```
    @Patch(':id')
    updateProject(@Param('id') accountId: string, @AnyValidBody() dataToUpdate: UpdateProjectDTO) {
        return dataToUpdate;
    }
```

For other ways to approach this, check out: https://gist.github.com/josephdpurcell/9af97c36148673de596ecaa7e5eb6a0a. It has links to other similar stack overflow questions too.

Answer (score 0):

Change your decorator to `@IsOptional()` from `@IsNotEmpty()`